# How to reassign a pull request on GitHub to a different user using command line?

Tags: github, github-cli, hub

I am using [hub](https://hub.github.com/hub.1.html) by github to create pull requests from command line. I even assign the pull request to a user using the command line.
However, I don't understand how do I reassign a pull request that was already created via the command line to a different user.

The command I use to create a pull request is:

```
hub pull-request -b <org_name>:main -h <branch_name>  -m "title of pull request" --assign <user_name>
```

If I use the same command to assign a different user then it returns an error saying that a pull request already exists. So any thoughts on how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `gh pr edit` from the github cli:

```
C:\Users\jesse>gh pr edit
--tile, --body, --reviewer, --assignee, --label, --project, or --milestone required when not running interactively

Usage:  gh pr edit [<number> | <url> | <branch>] [flags]

Flags:
      --add-assignee login      Add assigned users by their login. Use "@me" to assign yourself.
      --add-label name          Add labels by name
      --add-project name        Add the pull request to projects by name
      --add-reviewer login      Add reviewers by their login.
  -B, --base branch             Change the base branch for this pull request
  -b, --body string             Set the new body.
  -F, --body-file file          Read body text from file (use "-" to read from standard input)
  -m, --milestone name          Edit the milestone the pull request belongs to by name
      --remove-assignee login   Remove assigned users by their login. Use "@me" to unassign yourself.
      --remove-label name       Remove labels by name
      --remove-project name     Remove the pull request from projects by name
      --remove-reviewer login   Remove reviewers by their login.
  -t, --title string            Set the new title.
```

Something like:

```
gh pr edit --add-assignee jessehouwing --remove-assignee otherguy
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! It works like a charm :)